# NetSuite Saved Search: Adding replace formula to existing formula

Tags: netsuite, case-statement, saved-searches

I've created a Saved Search formula LOWER(CONCAT({custitem38}|| ' ', {custitem16})). This is formula is combining values from two custom fields in lower case. For example the result now show like this combining name and color fields "snow jacket orange stripes". I'm now trying to figure out how to replace any spaces with "-" so the results will display as "snow-jacket-orange-stripes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REPLACE(LOWER(CONCAT({custitem38}||'', {custitem16})), ' ', '-')

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to add additional replace lookups? There are some values with "/" and "." that also need to be replaced by "-"

Comment: Use TRANSLATE instead of REPLACE. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php Awesome!